# How do I remove the left padding in Netbeans editor?

Tags: netbeans

I have installed Netbeans for the purpose of editing Php.

I have disabled the right red line by setting it to position 0, but I see there is a padding on the left side between the line number itself and column 0 of the text.

I could not find any property for that, nor has google helped me on this aspect.

[image]

Please help me remove this, I have very limited width space and this is a medium problem for me.

I don't mind if it comes as a plugin or some sort of a hack.

Ty in advance peoples =^_^=

Comment: Yes, I would also like to remove this extra space, or at least turn it a different color.

Comment: You can remove part of the space by unchecking "Use Code Folding:" and "Show outline" the editor tab of Tools -> Options